# Remove header box from IPBoard?

Tags: php, html

One of our designers for site http://www.trainz.net/ has gone rogue and he's added a giant box with a Dremel ad in it.

I have no idea how to remove it. Self-hosted with full admin access.

Comment: Questions on SO are **never** urgent.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: My apologies, will not do it again. Regardless, I am thankful for the rapid assistance offered and a successful resolution to the problem found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either remove permanently this div from your page ***(only the first-one)***:-

```
<div class="ipsBox table_wrap">
   <div class="ipsBox_container">
    <a href="http://www.dremel.com"><img src="http://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Dremel_logo_logotype_wordmark.png" width="100%"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or if you are not able to remove above, then add this code to any of your CSS file:-

```
.ipsBox.table_wrap:nth-child(1) {
    display: none; /* or do display: none !important;*/
}
```

Or add JavaScript code like below:-

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ipsBox table_wrap")[0].style.display ="none";
```

Comment: @user3227564  i have changed the css code. Please check. gerard you can check also

Comment: new CSS works for me

Comment: I have found the issue. Was editing IP.Board template instead of a second Trainz.net template that the former designer added. All is well now.

Comment: Thank you @AlivetoDie and all of you.

Answer (score 1):

> Oh Noes! Rogue one! :)

Remove this-

```
<a href="http://www.dremel.com"><img src="http://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Dremel_logo_logotype_wordmark.png" width="100%"></a>
```

Full Div,

```
<div class="ipsBox table_wrap">
    <div class="ipsBox_container">
        <a href="http://www.dremel.com"><img src="http://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Dremel_logo_logotype_wordmark.png" width="100%"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why is this wrong?

Comment: It's correct.+1

Answer (score 0):

Add below css line to your css file:

```
#categories .ipsBox.table_wrap {
    display: none;
}

#categories div .ipsBox.table_wrap {
   display: block;
}
```